# Foundation accordion won't initialize on a VueJS v-if condition

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a problem on my accordion content. Here's my code

```
<template v-if="(claimGroupType == 'Pro-Risk' || claimGroupType == 'Liability' || claimGroupType == 'Property' || claimGroupType == 'Corporate-Travel')">
    <ul class="accordion" data-responsive-accordion-tabs="accordion medium-tabs large-accordion" data-allow-all-closed="true">
        <li class="accordion-item is-active" data-accordion-item>
            <a href="#" class="accordion-title"><h3 class="ins-subheader">Loss Information</h3></a>
            <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>

                <div class="grid-x">
                    <div class="cell large-12">
                        <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
                            <div v-for="claim in lossFieldsInformation" class="cell large-6 padding-bottom-1">
                                <claim-field ref="claimField"
                                    v-bind:claim-name="claim.name"
                                    v-bind:claim-field-type="claim.field_type"
                                    v-bind:claim-required="claim.required"
                                    v-bind:claim-value="claim.value"
                                    v-bind:claim-abide-pattern="getAbidePattern(claim.field_type)"
                                    v-bind:claim-label="claim.label"
                                    v-bind:claim-radio-checkbox-field-options="getRadioCheckboxFieldOptions(claim.label)"
                                    v-bind:claim-field-options="claim.options"
                                ></claim-field>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell auto"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

The problem is when I access it on my page it seems that the foundation accordion is not initializing.

Screenshot of built structure: https://cbo.d.pr/2CBiF3

But when I remove the v-if condition it will work.

Comment: Try to use the v-if inside the <ul> tag and not within the template tag.

Comment: Wrap the `ul` in a `div` and put the `v-if` on that, not the template tag

Comment: Thanks guys I will try those approach

Comment: hi @ThomasKleßen  still the same issue

Comment: hi @George same issue also. :(